# PHP if statement for Gravity PDF

Tags: php, pdf, gravity-forms-plugin

I was able to get my radio toggle to properly show depending on the input by using the PHP:

```
<?php if ( 'Yes' == $form_data['field'][25] ) {
echo '<div>This radio button says yes</div>';
} ?>
```

I would like to add similar functionality to a dropdown list.

My current PHP code looks as such:

```
<?php if ($form_data['field'][202] == 'Arts & Music'): ?> Arts & Music Selected <?php else: ?> Arts & Music Not Selected <?php endif; ?>
```

And my data array shows:

```
[202.Industry Keyword] => Arts & Music
[202] => Arts & Music
[Industry Keyword] => Arts & Music
[202.Industry Keyword_name] => Arts & Music
[202_name] => Arts & Music
[Industry Keyword_name] => Arts & Music
```

However, when I try adding this PHP statement to my custom template, it always displays "Arts & Music Not Selected"

Is there something that I am missing, or is the issue caused by something else? If you can help me out with this as well that would be perfect.

Thank you!

Comment: View the page source.  Maybe `&` is really `&amp;`.

Comment: That seems to have resolved the issue. I should have noticed that, sorry for bugging you!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that "&" should have been "&" Thank you AbraCadaver for your input!